# Where can I see java logs while doing api requests?

Tags: java

In my method I am using

```
 Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("testing");
 LOGGER.info("smth");
```

I wonder where can I see this log, while I do a api call and use this method ?

Comment: Into tomcat logs. If you are using tomcat server as an application server.

Comment: Depends on where the `Logger` comes from, how that logger is configured (considering your logging level, etc.)

Comment: Thx,I am very new to web,so I can enter ...../manager/html  or should log in by putty?

Comment: @ernest_k can you tell me where exactly should I loo for?I just make this looger in my ApiController class,and in one of my api calls I am creating it.

Comment: What framework is is the `Logger` class from (maybe just share the import statement)? Also, what's the runtime? Is this running on a server? If yes, which one?

Comment: `import java.util.logging.Logger;` I am using this in api call method

`@GetMapping(path = "/getByCategoryId")
    public @ResponseBody
    ListTransferDTO findProductsByCategoryId(@RequestHeader String authToken, @RequestParam Integer userId, @RequestParam Integer supplierId, @RequestParam Integer categoryId) {...`

The server is tomcat I guess,sorry if I missunderstand smth,I am an android developer and should do some fix now on web)))

Comment: `java.util.logging.Logger` isn't a feature-rich logging framework, so chances are that your output is going to stdout. Tomcat logs are typically under `<tomcat-install-directory>/logs/catalina.out`. These files may roll over and you might have to look in other files with a similar name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174939/discussion-between-laurent-koscielny-and-ernest-k).